# How read .mat openmodelica result file in python correctly?

Tags: python, mat, openmodelica

I tried to read modelica resul file (.mat) in python and used code like this:

```
data = scipy.io.loadmat('TPPSim.Boilers.Tests.EMA_028_HRSG_Test_res.mat')
print data.keys()
['Aclass', 'dataInfo', 'name', 'data_2', 'data_1', 'description']

names = [''.join(s).rstrip() for s in zip(*data['name'])]
len(names)    
899
```

But it's not all variables that i can see in 'OMEdit plotting'. I think that's only variables that have derivatives in simulation.

And data['data_1'] have more than 899 sets of data:

```
data['data_2'][0]
4192L
```

How I can get all results in Python?

Sorry for my bad English.

Artyom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a Python library that handles the format, such as [DyMat](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/DyMat)

```
d = DyMat.DyMatFile('TPPSim.Boilers.Tests.EMA_028_HRSG_Test_res.mat')
print(d.names())
```

Comment: Yes, It's works. I thought 'DyMat' use scipy.io like I wrote, but I was wrong. Thank you.